# How to delete a block but keep the content in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper

I will show through an example that I want:

orignal state:

```
using (var myobject = new DisposableObject())
{
  //some code that no longer use myobject
  int x = 5;
  int y = x+5;
}
```

desired state:

```
  //some code that no longer use myobject
  int x = 5;
  int y = x+5;
```

I would like to achieve this change with a keyboard combination or a resharper command or maybe a macro. So not through deleting both of the curly brackets and the using line by hand. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a single command but this will work (needs Resharper):

- delete the "using" line (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>del</kbd>)
- put the cursor on the `{` and hit <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>enter</kbd>,
- choose "remove braces".

Comment: That's great :). shift+del, end, alt+enter, enter. Isn't it possible to write a macro on these 4 steps?

Answer (score 0):

This macro also works if the braces and the using block are in a different lines, just needs a shortcut to be added:

```
Sub deleteusingblock()
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.LineDelete")
    DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.EndOfLine()
    Dim sel As TextSelection = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection
    Dim ap As VirtualPoint = sel.ActivePoint

    If (sel.Text() <> "") Then Exit Sub
    ' reposition
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoToBrace") : DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoToBrace")

    If (ap.DisplayColumn <= ap.LineLength) Then sel.CharRight(True)

    Dim c As String = sel.Text
    Dim isRight As Boolean = False
    If (c <> "(" And c <> "[" And c <> "{") Then
        sel.CharLeft(True, 1 + IIf(c = "", 0, 1))
        c = sel.Text
        sel.CharRight()
        If (c <> ")" And c <> "]" And c <> "}") Then Exit Sub
        isRight = True
    End If

    Dim line = ap.Line
    Dim pos = ap.DisplayColumn
    DTE.ExecuteCommand("Edit.GoToBrace")
    If (isRight) Then sel.CharRight(True) Else sel.CharLeft(True)

    sel.Text = ""
    If (isRight And line = ap.Line) Then pos = pos - 1
    sel.MoveToDisplayColumn(line, pos)
    sel.CharLeft(True)
    sel.Text = ""
End Sub
```

(source: chris's answer: [Delete Matching Braces in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896859/delete-matching-braces-in-visual-studio) )