# Commenting out / removing useless braces in C# using Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Sometimes when I'm developing I may have a control structure that I want to remove (`if`/`for`/`foreach`) so I will comment out the actual control line, leaving the braces at the start and end.

At a later stage I may want to remove these two braces together, but have to hunt around code to get to the end brace from the start brace. I know about the shortcut `CTRL`+`]` to hit the end brace when on the start brace, but I still then have to go back to the start brace. Is there an editor feature or shortcut that I can use to comment out both braces together in one command?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, I don't think there is any in-built functionality. It seems suspicious to me that you're commenting out the braces, rather than deleting them entirely once you've decided the `if` statement should be gone. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9896859/delete-matching-braces-in-visual-studio) provides a solution for deleting the brackets via macros, which you can probably tailor to use commenting instead

Comment: R# (Resharper) has capabilities of removing unnecessary braces using the good old (Alt+Enter) shortcut.  I highly recommend it.

Comment: @Ruskin thanks! It's a shame there isn't a native feature for this, but the R# method will work. I never thought about hitting alt+enter on the brace!